Plotting LocalTime on the X-axis of a LineChart in Java FX 8
Is it possible to plot LocalTime data on the X-axis in a LineChart?
I would like dynamically added LocalTime values ​​on the X-axis to be sorted ascending.
When trying to add LocalTime values ​​on the X-axis using the code below, no data is drawn on the chart and my logger shows an error:
javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.toNumericValue(CategoryAxis.java:67)
@FXML
private LineChart<LocalTime, Number> chart;
observer.addChart(chart);

and in Observer.java:
public void addChart(LineChart chart) {
    this.chart = chart;
}

XYChart.Series<LocalTime, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
chart.getData().add(series);
chart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(LocalTime.parse("11:05:45.207"), Integer.valueOf("5")));

When I use String on the X-axis instead of LocalTime, everything works fine. This error is somewhat similar to this: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092916

Arrange that your logger record the full stack trace

You cannot pass a Time, or DateTime object, where the code is expecting a string. You need to convert your values to strings before passing them to the chart builder.

Unfortunately, the chart API is not well designed for this. You might be able to make it work just formatting the dates and using a LineChart<String, Number>. A more robust solution, which is going to be quite a bit more work, would be to use a LineChart<LocalDate, Number> and define your own DateAxis extends Axis<LocalDate> to use as the x-axis. You can look at the source code for ValueAxis to get some ideas for the implementation.

Ideally, ValueAxis should have been written as a subclass of Axis<T extends Comparable<T>>, instead of Axis<T extends Number>, so you could inherit the implementation defined in ValueAxis. But it is what it is.

@James_D Thanks for the tip and link. I just had LineChart<String, Number> before and it worked fine. However, I'm looking for a solution where the time will be sorted ascending in case data with an older time appears for many series. Your solution will probably solve my problem.

The StatusController seen here "displays a graph of recent memory usage." The (inevitable) drift may be (un)acceptable for your use.
